# Ruby: break string into words by capital letters and acronyms

Tags: regex, ruby, string, split, acronym

I need to break a string into several strings by capital letters and acronyms, I could do this:

```rb
myString.scan(/[A-Z][a-z]+/)
```

But it works for only capital letters, in cases like:

```
QuickFoxReadingPDF
```

or

```
LazyDogASAPSleep
```

The all-capital acronyms are missing in the result.

What should I change the RegEx to, or are there any alternatives?

Thanks!

Update:

Later I found some of my data has digits, like "RabbitHole3", It would be great if the solution could consider digits, ie. `["Rabbit", "Hole3"]`.

Comment: Shouldn’t that be `/[A-Z][a-z]*/`, at least, then? `[a-z]+` means _at least one lower-case letter_ which is clearly missing at `PDF`. Do you want `PDF` as a single token or `P`, `D`, and `F` as separate tokens?

Comment: Thanks @user4642212 I want `PDF` as a single token.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
s.split(/(?<=\p{Ll})(?=\p{Lu})|(?<=\p{Lu})(?=\p{Lu}\p{Ll})/)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/4gTvYH/1).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \p{Ll}                 any lowercase letter
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \p{Lu}                 any uppercase letter
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \p{Lu}                 any uppercase letter
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \p{Lu}\p{Ll}           any uppercase letter, any lowercase letter
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

[Ruby code](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v7ikSMFWQT2wNDM52y2/Iig1MSUzLz3AxU2dq0ABKKlXXJCTWaKhr2FvYxtTUO2TU6upYQ9mldZq1sBES5FEoar0Nf//BwA):

```rb
str = 'QuickFoxReadingPDF'
p str.split(/(?<=\p{Ll})(?=\p{Lu})|(?<=\p{Lu})(?=\p{Lu}\p{Ll})/)
```

Results: `["Quick", "Fox", "Reading", "PDF"]`

Comment: Thanks, this works better than the previously selected answer, it also considers digits, e.g. `RabbitHole3` becomes "Rabbit Hole3" whereas the previous ticked answer gets rid of the digit.

Comment: @hzxu Oh, but you never mentioned digits. Your attempt was `/[A-Z][a-z]+/` which also would have never matched digits. A less vague question description would’ve helped here.

Comment: @hzxu Glad it worked, an upvote would also be helpful  for future visitors, I think.

Comment: Sorry @user4642212 I didn't realize my data set has strings with digits in it, just found out while testing this solution and found it also takes into account those digits.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern `[A-Z][a-z]+` matches a single uppercase char A-Z and one or more lowercase chars a-z which does not take multiple uppercase chars into account.

In this case, you also want to match an uppercase char when it is not directly followed by a lowercase char `a-z`.

Not sure if an acronym can consist of a single uppercase char, but if there there should be at least 2 uppercase chars

```
[A-Z][a-z]+|[A-Z]{2,}(?![a-z])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0H3nWO/1)